# require is not defined with dayjs in vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, dayjs

I need to use the dayjs library in my Vue application but Vite does not allow me to use require as specified in the dayjs documentation.
I searched a lot on the web but the little solution I could find didn't work.
Do you have a solution to fix this ?

Thanks in advance

here is the file i am importing from :

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const isoWeek = require('dayjs/plugin/isoWeek');
dayjs.extend(isoWeek);
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');
dayjs.extend(utc);
```

the error message in the console :

```
vue-router.esm-bundler.js:3308 
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.js:3:17
```

Comment: use `import` instead ... just like on the first line e.g. `import isoWeek from 'dayjs/plugin/isoWeek';`

Comment: Thank you very much @Bravo!
So it was so simple 